# Random consts on initialization lists

Tags: c++, list, initialization

There seems to be an issue when I try to make initialization list with a const number while its a random number, cant realy figure out the problem and didnt found a proper solution when I use random const's on initizilation lists.

die.h

```
#ifndef die
#define die
#include <iostream>
#include "time.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

class die{
private:
    const int dieFaces;

public:
    die();

        // Getters
        int getFaces();
        // Common Functions
        void printDie(die);
        void roll();
        int copyConstructor(die);

    // Destructors
        ~die(){};
};
#endif die
```

die.cpp

```
#include "die.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "time.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <random>
using namespace std;

// Constructor
die::die() : dieFaces(rand() % 20 + 1){};
```

the error i'm getting is "Declartion does not declare anything" while on the task I was asked to create an empty constructor.

and in the CPP file it seems to expect all sorts of ";" and "Declartion of Variable expected"...

Any help will be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Voting to close, because the question description is nothing that anyone would ever search for, and it seems unlikely that this question has any benefit for the community.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the include guard `die`: it's the same as the class name.

The preprocessor will substitute empty text every time it sees the string `die`. The compiler will see

```
class {
private:
```

etc., which is not compilable.

Use something like `#define included_die_hpp` instead.